# Is there any JDBC driver for Hibernate Entities

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, orm

Is there any project, or JDBC that connects to the Hibernate Layer?

IN other words, I want to map entities and SubSelects from 2 data bases and join them on a layer on the top of Hibernate - my current ORM framework - using SQL and a JDBC driver, to connect to it.

Comment: Why would you put SQL on top of Hibernate? You will end up doing Relational - Object - Relational mapping, rendering the Object Oriented middleware totally useless.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev  - The sql is supposed to join one table from one Database, with another table/subselect from another database, and maybe a third database, and so on. And the SQL brings the flexibility of choosing how to join the tables from multiple DBs. You know the idea is to provide a single interface through JDBC to all Mapped Databases.

Comment: You can check to see if hibernate supports this out of the box. There is the `catalog` property in the `Table` annotation, maybe it will work for you.